# How to copy multiple ranges from 13 different sheets to a another workbook in Google Docs

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google Spreadsheet with 13 sheets.  Each sheet has the same formatting and layout but the data varies.  The ranges I need from each sheet are F7:G13 and cell F2. Each row within the F7:G13 range should be paired with Cell F2 and placed into 3 adjacent columns in another workbook (we'll call it Workbook2).  So if there is a data point in column F there will be a data point in the adjacent G cell.  As long as there is data in the G:F range then the contents of cell F2 needs to be copied over too.

Some potential problems...
The number of rows in the F:G range will vary from 0 to 7 on any given sheet.
Workbook2 has some auto-populated cells (range F1:J14) which will do some calculations based on information copied over.  I mention this because unless there is a way to use appendRow on a specific cell range (A:C) it will copy the data starting in row 15 which I do not want.

I think i've included everything but I will gladly clarify anything.  Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: If you provide example spreadsheets with input and desired output, I'll take a look.